# How to: Create an Event Handler Feature

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I was testing the code provided in below MSDN Link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx

But I got **compile time** error as "Error1Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': Cannot start service SPUserCodeV4 on computer 'ComputerName'. $000DeletingEventReceiver"$0

Not sure what's wrong!! any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it from Central Admin first, see: http://troyscott.ca/2010/08/06/cannot-start-service-spusercodev4-on-computer/

[image]

**OR**

Go to run and type services.msc and open it. Please found SharePoint 2010 User Code Host and make sure that it is started. Once the Service starts the issue will resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Central Administration Central > System Settings > Manage services on server and make sure the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service" is started.

Comment: "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation User Code Service" is not listed over there!!

Comment: Sorry, make that the "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service."

Answer (score 0):

The TechNet article [Enable sandboxed solutions on the farm (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff535775.aspx) lists two methods for starting the service:

1. From the Services on Server page of the Central Administration website, click **Start** in the **Action** column of the **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service** row.
2. From PowerShell, execute the following command: `Start-Service -Name SPUserCodeV4`